# Hide div based on display value of parent

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of divs with class `js-season-list-item` that each have inline style of `style="display: none;"` or `style="display: block;"`. These are wrapped in a parent class of `series-seasons-list-wrap`. I need to be able to loop through the parent class and find the `js-season-list-item` with inline style currently set to `style="display: block;"`. If it is, I need to be able to check the `data-episode-count` value and if it is less than 6, I need it to set the display of the `show-more` class to none.
Essentially, when a user is switching between different season views, if the currently visible one (set to display: block) is visible, the script should check that value of `data-episode-count`. If that value is less than 6, the "show more" button should be set to display none. This is triggered when the user switches between series.

**HTML**

```js
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('js-show-more-trigger');
let wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('series-seasons-list-wrap');
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("season-list");
for(let i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < seasonList.length; j++ ) {
      if(seasonList[i].getAttribute('data-episode-count') < 6){
      trigger[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="series-seasons-list-wrap">
<div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: none;">
  <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="7">
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099013"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099014"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099015"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
 <div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: block;">
  <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="3">
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099013"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099014"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099015"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
  
<div class="show-more"><span class="js-show-more-trigger">Show 
More</span></div>
```

Codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/testermytesty/pen/xWdgzX)

Comment: Different question. My script finds the data attribute, but I'm having trouble looping through the parent class to find the season list with display set to block.

Comment: Main problem here seems to be this line, `if(seasonList[i].getAttribute('data-episode-count') < 6)`, where the returned value from `getAttribute` is of type `string` and you match it against a `number`.

Comment: The you missed `; j++` in `for(let j = 0; j < seasonList.length; j++)` ... and I can't find any element having an attribute named `data-episode-count`?

Comment: Thanks, fixed the loop. However, I believe I need a conditional to check within the outter loop for which `js-season-list-item` has display block. Also, the `data-episode-count` is right next to each `season-list` class.

Comment: @LGSon - I should be able to get the inline style with `elementStyle.hasOwnProperty(prop)`, but this isn't giving me the style based on the class.

Comment: @LGSon - Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong index on `seasonList` in the loop, should be `j` not `i`.

You were comparing a `string` value to a `number` value (not apocalyptic, but best to ensure that it is a number value).

Finally, you are getting the `trigger` `div` using `getElementsByClassName`, this returns an `array`.
You only have one of these divs, so you can't use the current index in the loop to access the array (there is only [0]).

Better to use an `id` for this and `getElementById`.

If you will have several of these on the page, then they should be enclosed in each season (not outside), then use the correct indexer to retrieve it.

I've moved it into the wrapper, because I think that's what you wanted.

Here's the working code (for what you have supplied):

```js
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('js-show-more-trigger');
let wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('series-seasons-list-wrap');
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("season-list");
for (let i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < seasonList.length; j++) {
        let count = parseInt(seasonList[j].getAttribute('data-episode-count'));
        if (count < 6) {
            trigger[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="series-seasons-list-wrap">
    <div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: none;">
        <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="7">
            <div class="season-list__item">
                <div class="episode-item">
                    <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
                        <div class="episode-card__overlay">
                            <a href="/play/3099013">
                                <span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013">
                                    <svg class="svg svg-play">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episode-details">
                        <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
                        <p></p>
                        <p class="runtime">21min</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="season-list__item">
                <div class="episode-item">
                    <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
                        <div class="episode-card__overlay">
                            <a href="/play/3099014">
                                <span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014">
                                    <svg class="svg svg-play">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episode-details">
                        <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
                        <p></p>
                        <p class="runtime">21min</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="season-list__item">
                <div class="episode-item">
                    <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
                        <div class="episode-card__overlay">
                            <a href="/play/3099015">
                                <span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015">
                                    <svg class="svg svg-play">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episode-details">
                        <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
                        <p></p>
                        <p class="runtime">21min</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: block;">
        <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="3">
            <div class="season-list__item">
                <div class="episode-item">
                    <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
                        <div class="episode-card__overlay">
                            <a href="/play/3099013">
                                <span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013">
                                    <svg class="svg svg-play">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episode-details">
                        <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
                        <p></p>
                        <p class="runtime">21min</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="season-list__item">
                <div class="episode-item">
                    <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
                        <div class="episode-card__overlay">
                            <a href="/play/3099014">
                                <span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014">
                                    <svg class="svg svg-play">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episode-details">
                        <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
                        <p></p>
                        <p class="runtime">21min</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="season-list__item">
                <div class="episode-item">
                    <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
                        <div class="episode-card__overlay">
                            <a href="/play/3099015">
                                <span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015">
                                    <svg class="svg svg-play">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="episode-details">
                        <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
                        <p></p>
                        <p class="runtime">21min</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <span class="js-show-more-trigger">Show More
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Matt, just moved the `div` inside the wrapper, I'm guessing that's what you wanted.